# Metacity malfunction preventing custom Gnome session from launching?

Tags: 12.04, unity-2d, window-manager, metacity, gnome-session

When I try to run Metacity in Ubuntu2D(12.04), I get the following message:

```
alisa@ubuntu:~$ metacity 
Window manager warning: Screen 0 on display ":2.0" already has a window manager; 
try using the --replace option to replace the current window manager.
```

I get the same message when running Compiz from the command line in 3D (it opens fine through the GUI). I understand that these *should* be the default managers for the respective sessions.

I'm trying to create a custom Gnome session using the following instructions: [unity launcher-free session](http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/06/how-to-disable-unity-launcher-and-use.html). Here is what I've put into my .session file (note the reference to Metacity):

```
[GNOME Session]
Name=Custom Unity2D Session
RequiredComponents=gnome-settings-daemon;
RequiredProviders=windowmanager;panel;
DefaultProvider-windowmanager=metacity
DefaultProvider-panel=unity-2d-panel
FallbackSession=ubuntu-2d
DesktopName=GNOME
```

**I can't launch the custom session** (it does show up on my login screen). I think Metacity might be the problem, since it's not recognized as the default. Please let me know if you think there may be other issues affecting my custom session. I am new to Linux, so list anything you think might be helpful. Thank you!

**Update**: Metacity seems to be the default...

```
alisa@ubuntu:~$ tail /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome-fallback.session
[GNOME Session]
Name=GNOME fallback (Safe Mode)
RequiredComponents=gnome-panel;gnome-settings-daemon;
RequiredProviders=windowmanager;
DefaultProvider-windowmanager=metacity
DefaultProvider-notifications=notify-osd
DesktopName=GNOME

alisa@ubuntu:~$ tail /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/ubuntu-2d.session
[GNOME Session]
Name=Ubuntu 2D
RequiredComponents=gnome-settings-daemon;
RequiredProviders=windowmanager;panel;shell;
DefaultProvider-windowmanager=metacity
DefaultProvider-panel=unity-2d-panel
DefaultProvider-shell=unity-2d-shell
DesktopName=Unity
```

So why the terminal "window manager warning" message?

Comment: I tried specifying Metacity as my default manager by adding `exec metacity` to the .xinitrc file, and I tried running `metacity --replace`, but neither worked.

Comment: AWN behaves the same way as Compiz: it can be launched from GUI but not from terminal. I can't launch Metacity at all but I can find the associated files using 'locate'.

Comment: **Update #2**: I changed the permissions for Metacity through sudo nautilus to enable it to be run as an executable (since Compiz and AWN run fine from GUI but not from terminal), and got the same warning message as above. =(

Comment: Metacity is the default window manager for Unity2d, you don't need to run it from within the session, because it autostarts.

Comment: Yeah, I have since noticed it in my open processes--but I'm pretty sure it's supposed to have a GUI, which I haven't managed to open.